# Conversion of nested stdclassobject to a double dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to convert a `double` std class object i.e (stdclass object having again a stdclass object in it) into an array?

I have user type; casting it only converted the single object but the object inside remained same.

**Data:**

```
Array ( [activities] => Array ( ) [goals] => stdClass Object (
        [activeMinutes] => 30 [caloriesOut] => 3355 
        [distance] => 8.05 [steps] =>  10000 ) 

[summary] => stdClass Object ( [activeScore] => -1 [activityCalories] 
          => 1472 [caloriesBMR] => 2074 [caloriesOut] => 3308  

[distances] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [activity] => total [distance] => 8.46 ) [1] => stdClass 

Object ( [activity] => tracker [distance] => 8.46 ) 

[2] => stdClass Object ( 
[activity] => loggedActivities [distance] => 0 ) 

[3] => stdClass Object ( 
[activity] => veryActive [distance] => 2.35 ) 

[4] => stdClass Object ( 
[activity] => moderatelyActive [distance] => 1.63 ) 

[5] => stdClass Object ( 
[activity] => lightlyActive [distance] => 4.48 ) 

[6] => stdClass Object ( [activity] => sedentaryActive [distance] => 0 ) ) 

[fairlyActiveMinutes] => 32 
[lightlyActiveMinutes] => 194 [marginalCalories] => 867 [sedentaryMinutes] => 
1125 [steps] => 11446 [veryActiveMinutes] => 31 ) )
```

This data has `stdclass` object inside an array how to convert that also into an array and make it on the whole as a `double` dimensional array.

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: try json_decode(json_encode($yourArray),1);

Comment: how to fix my formatting?????                                                                                            actually i wanted to print the data in the foreach using an array but there are classobjects also in that they are not getting converted into arrays when i perform typecasting..my question is how to convert a nested object structure into its equivalent array(any no.of dimensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have something like:

```
<?php
$a = [
    'foo' => (object)[
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'foo',
    ],
    'bar' => (object)[
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'bar',
        'nested' => (object)['status' => 'ok'],
    ],
];
var_export($a);
```

Result:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => 1,
     'name' => 'foo',
  )),
  'bar' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => 2,
     'name' => 'bar',
     'nested' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'status' => 'ok',
    )),
  )),
)
```

And you try to receive something like:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'foo',
  ),
  'bar' => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'bar',
    'nested' => 
    array (
      'status' => 'ok',
    ),
  ),
)
```

So the best way done it - is like mentioned @MineshPatel use next code:

```
var_export(json_decode(json_encode($a), true));
```

Comment: thanks alot its working.......but when i print this arrayit is showing a notice that array cannot be converted to string (this is because i have an array inside the main array which i am printing .)how to resolve this???